# Insert data in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I got a .txt file with some data that i would like to import into a google sheet document.

The text file looks like this:

```
                ["Note"] = "<00001>",
                ["Name"] = "test1",
                ["Note"] = "<00002>",
                ["Name"] = "test2",
                ["Note"] = "<00003>",
                ["Name"] = "test3",
                ["Note"] = "<00004>",
                ["Name"] = "test4",
                ["Note"] = "<00005>",
                ["Name"] = "test5",
```

I want it in 2 columns, 1 named Note and the other one named Name, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it into a [`.csv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and then load it into Google Spreadsheets.

For example, you data would look like that: (*The first row represent the titles of each column*)

```
Note,Name
<00001>,test1
<00002>,test2
<00003>,test3
<00004>,test4
<00005>,test5
```

Which then would be imported as:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i want, but how dos i change it to a .csv with only wht text i want?

Comment: Where do you get your output from? You created it that way? I just used `notepad++` search and replace to achieve that change.

Comment: I get the output emailed to me as it is there. when i use the search and replace function  in notepad++ i can´t get the data sorted the way you do, mine still looks like:

Comment: Note,<00001>
                Name,test1
                Note,<00002>
                Name,test2
                Note,<00003>",
                Name,test3",
                Note,<00004>
                Name,test4
                Note,<00005>
                Name,test5

Comment: Just remove the first 12 characters of each row, and the last two. And then combine every two lines with a comma. Add a new first line with the title, manually, and that's it.

Comment: @NovoDK got it?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already in Sheets (say A2:A11) and you are prepared to add the column labels manually, then copied down to suit, in B2:

```
=left(mid(offset($A2,int((row()-2)),),find("=",offset($A2,int((row()-2)),))+3,50),len(mid(offset($A2,int((row()-2)),),find("=",offset($A2,int((row()-2)),))+3,50))-2)
```

in C2:

```
=left(mid(offset($A2,1+int((row()-2)),),find("=",offset($A2,1+int((row()-2)),))+3,50),len(mid(offset($A2,1+int((row()-2)),),find("=",offset($A2,int((row()-2)),))+3,50))-2)
```